# run app from localhost in android webview

Tags: android

I am developing a mobile application with JQuery Mobile. I have to stream different channels and for that I am using Hls.js. After adding the following code I had to run the app in localhost on my PC because without that the stream wasn't loading.

I am loading the application in a webview from assets folder. But the stream is not working (possibly due to not running it on a server) .

I am curious that how can I run the app on localhost in a webview?

```
if (Hls.isSupported()) {
  var video = document.getElementById('video');
  var hls = new Hls();
  // bind them together
  hls.attachMedia(video);
  // MEDIA_ATTACHED event is fired by hls object once MediaSource is ready
  hls.on(Hls.Events.MEDIA_ATTACHED, function () {
        console.log("video and hls.js are now bound together !");
         hls.loadSource("http://mystream.m3u8");
    hls.on(Hls.Events.MANIFEST_PARSED, function (event, data) {
      console.log("manifest loaded, found " + data.levels.length + " quality level");
      video.play();
    });
  });
}
```